# Change title of window [Tkinter Python3]

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following question regarding Tkinter for my upcoming project, i seem to have hit a road block regarding the changing of the title.

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and i need your help just changing the title of the window globally. So, i know i use the following code to change the title:

```
program = Tk()
program.title('My Window')
mainloop()
```

Opening the window, isn't the issue nor changing the title of the window but when i hover the icon of the program or i am actively on the window, it shows a different title but while running it displays in both scenarios the default "Tk"

[image: Image 1]

My question is the following, how do i change the name to be globally instead of just the window?